# xsetwacom can't map keys correctly

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout, wacom, graphics-tablet

I recently bought a Wacom Intuos listed with `xsetwacom` as `Wacom Intuos PT M`. I figured out how to configure the buttons and actions, but when I try to set any button to some particular letters, they are replaced by others. Here is a table of the results

```
Letter | Letter
typed  | mapped
---------------
   a   |   **q**
   b   |   b
   c   |   c
   d   |   d
   e   |   e
   f   |   f
   g   |   g
   h   |   h
   i   |   i
   j   |   j
   k   |   k
   l   |   l
   m   |   **é**
   n   |   n
   o   |   o
   p   |   p
   q   |   q
   r   |   r
   s   |   s
   t   |   t
   u   |   u
   v   |   v
   w   |   w
   x   |   x
   y   |   **z**
   z   |   **w**
(more with the non-letter characters)
```

The keyboard looky PARTIALLY mapped as an AZERTY (French) keyboard, but not totally. I therefore can't map the letters **a**, **m** and **y**, because both **a** and **q** produce **q**.

Do anybody know a workaround, like using unicode to map letters?

---

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, 64bit with a Swiss keyboard (QWERTZ).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and had to find the correct buttons by trial and error (cfr. [this blog post of mine](http://bartssolutions.blogspot.be/2015/02/how-to-configure-wacom-intuos-express.html) for the whole story). It was the only solution I found.

I filed a bug report related to this issue here: [#274 Azerty keyboard/modifiers treated as (weird) QWERTY](http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/274/?limit=25) on Sourceforge. As mentioned there, possibly this issue has been fixed in the xsetwacom 0.29 release (haven't tested this).